# MATLAB-Contours in pgfplots: Intersecting contour lines when loading from file

Tags: pgfplots, matlab

I generated contours with Matlab, and saved them to a file as explained in the pgfplots manual. I wished to load this file in pgfplots to plot the contours, using

```
\pgfplotstableread[]{contours_plant.dat} \datatable
```

However, the result was a figure in which the contour lines intersected, see below:

[image: Contours when loaded from .dat file]

Interestingly, this behaviour did not occur when I copied the content of the contour.dat file directly into Latex:

[image: Contours when data was copied from file into Latex source code]

To reproduce the result, the code for the latter is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
% loading the data from the table does not seem to work:
% \pgfplotstableread[]{contours_plant.dat} \datatable
\addplot[contour prepared,
    contour prepared format=matlab] table {  
        -5.0000000e+01   2.0000000e+00
        5.9994090e+00   7.0000000e+01
        6.0000000e+00   7.0003299e+01
        0.0000000e+00   1.8000000e+01
        5.4873383e+00   7.0000000e+01
        5.5102041e+00   7.0126283e+01
        5.5510204e+00   7.0351044e+01
        5.5918367e+00   7.0574396e+01
        5.5987523e+00   7.0612245e+01
        5.6326531e+00   7.0801531e+01
        5.6734694e+00   7.1028242e+01
        5.7089927e+00   7.1224490e+01
        5.7142857e+00   7.1254339e+01
        5.7551020e+00   7.1484531e+01
        5.7959184e+00   7.1713196e+01
        5.8180374e+00   7.1836735e+01
        5.8367347e+00   7.1943381e+01
        5.8775510e+00   7.2175568e+01
        5.9183673e+00   7.2406196e+01
        5.9259433e+00   7.2448980e+01
        5.9591837e+00   7.2640769e+01
        6.0000000e+00   7.2874965e+01
        5.0000000e+01   3.8000000e+01
        4.9034519e+00   7.0000000e+01
        4.9387755e+00   7.0187654e+01
        4.9795918e+00   7.0403472e+01
        5.0193004e+00   7.0612245e+01
        5.0204082e+00   7.0618203e+01
        5.0612245e+00   7.0838566e+01
        5.1020408e+00   7.1057519e+01
        5.1332884e+00   7.1224490e+01
        5.1428571e+00   7.1276821e+01
        5.1836735e+00   7.1500287e+01
        5.2244898e+00   7.1722268e+01
        5.2455742e+00   7.1836735e+01
        5.2653061e+00   7.1946419e+01
        5.3061224e+00   7.2172894e+01
        5.3469388e+00   7.2397815e+01
        5.3562168e+00   7.2448980e+01
        5.3877551e+00   7.2627127e+01
        5.4285714e+00   7.2856534e+01
        5.4652129e+00   7.3061224e+01
        5.4693878e+00   7.3085128e+01
        5.5102041e+00   7.3319139e+01
        5.5510204e+00   7.3551414e+01
        5.5725282e+00   7.3673469e+01
        5.5918367e+00   7.3785824e+01
        5.6326531e+00   7.4022711e+01
        5.6734694e+00   7.4257806e+01
        5.6783109e+00   7.4285714e+01
        5.7142857e+00   7.4498438e+01
        5.7551020e+00   7.4738159e+01
        5.7824376e+00   7.4897959e+01
        5.7959184e+00   7.4978850e+01
        5.8367347e+00   7.5223334e+01
        5.8775510e+00   7.5465859e+01
        5.8850168e+00   7.5510204e+01
        5.9183673e+00   7.5713622e+01
        5.9591837e+00   7.5960937e+01
        5.9859728e+00   7.6122449e+01
        6.0000000e+00   7.6209346e+01
        1.0000000e+02   6.3000000e+01
        4.1381549e+00   7.0000000e+01
        4.1632653e+00   7.0111867e+01
        4.2040816e+00   7.0294941e+01
        4.2448980e+00   7.0478038e+01
        4.2746926e+00   7.0612245e+01
        4.2857143e+00   7.0663276e+01
        4.3265306e+00   7.0854203e+01
        4.3673469e+00   7.1044812e+01
        4.4058556e+00   7.1224490e+01
        4.4081633e+00   7.1235561e+01
        4.4489796e+00   7.1433686e+01
        4.4897959e+00   7.1631198e+01
        4.5306122e+00   7.1828108e+01
        4.5323816e+00   7.1836735e+01
        4.5714286e+00   7.2032493e+01
        4.6122449e+00   7.2236386e+01
        4.6530612e+00   7.2439435e+01
        4.6549625e+00   7.2448980e+01
        4.6938776e+00   7.2649937e+01
        4.7346939e+00   7.2859764e+01
        4.7740622e+00   7.3061224e+01
        4.7755102e+00   7.3068851e+01
        4.8163265e+00   7.3285516e+01
        4.8571429e+00   7.3500891e+01
        4.8899525e+00   7.3673469e+01
        4.8979592e+00   7.3716833e+01
        4.9387755e+00   7.3938890e+01
        4.9795918e+00   7.4159482e+01
        5.0029677e+00   7.4285714e+01
        5.0204082e+00   7.4382722e+01
        5.0612245e+00   7.4609867e+01
        5.1020408e+00   7.4835393e+01
        5.1133377e+00   7.4897959e+01
        5.1428571e+00   7.5066420e+01
        5.1836735e+00   7.5298392e+01
        5.2211883e+00   7.5510204e+01
        5.2244898e+00   7.5529424e+01
        5.2653061e+00   7.5767956e+01
        5.3061224e+00   7.6004531e+01
        5.3265016e+00   7.6122449e+01
        5.3469388e+00   7.6244426e+01
        5.3877551e+00   7.6487484e+01
        5.4285714e+00   7.6728468e+01
        5.4296219e+00   7.6734694e+01
        5.4693878e+00   7.6977863e+01
        5.5102041e+00   7.7225270e+01
        5.5303289e+00   7.7346939e+01
        5.5510204e+00   7.7476112e+01
        5.5918367e+00   7.7730085e+01
        5.6289606e+00   7.7959184e+01
        5.6326531e+00   7.7982730e+01
        5.6734694e+00   7.8243422e+01
        5.7142857e+00   7.8501553e+01
        5.7253425e+00   7.8571429e+01
        5.7551020e+00   7.8765845e+01
        5.7959184e+00   7.9030663e+01
        5.8196188e+00   7.9183673e+01
        5.8367347e+00   7.9297985e+01
        5.8775510e+00   7.9569657e+01
        5.9118367e+00   7.9795918e+01
        5.9183673e+00   7.9840535e+01
        5.9591837e+00   8.0119242e+01
        6.0000000e+00   8.0394914e+01
        1.5000000e+02   7.0000000e+01
        4.0000000e+00   7.4842536e+01
        4.0178426e+00   7.4897959e+01
        4.0408163e+00   7.4972437e+01
        4.0816327e+00   7.5110876e+01
        4.1224490e+00   7.5253284e+01
        4.1632653e+00   7.5399246e+01
        4.1934359e+00   7.5510204e+01
        4.2040816e+00   7.5551035e+01
        4.2448980e+00   7.5713251e+01
        4.2857143e+00   7.5877744e+01
        4.3265306e+00   7.6044264e+01
        4.3452534e+00   7.6122449e+01
        4.3673469e+00   7.6218610e+01
        4.4081633e+00   7.6399513e+01
        4.4489796e+00   7.6581476e+01
        4.4830495e+00   7.6734694e+01
        4.4897959e+00   7.6766321e+01
        4.5306122e+00   7.6961850e+01
        4.5714286e+00   7.7157625e+01
        4.6108334e+00   7.7346939e+01
        4.6122449e+00   7.7354009e+01
        4.6530612e+00   7.7562652e+01
        4.6938776e+00   7.7770854e+01
        4.7308059e+00   7.7959184e+01
        4.7346939e+00   7.7979862e+01
        4.7755102e+00   7.8200333e+01
        4.8163265e+00   7.8419782e+01
        4.8444830e+00   7.8571429e+01
        4.8571429e+00   7.8642555e+01
        4.8979592e+00   7.8873755e+01
        4.9387755e+00   7.9103437e+01
        4.9529410e+00   7.9183673e+01
        4.9795918e+00   7.9341191e+01
        5.0204082e+00   7.9582174e+01
        5.0568277e+00   7.9795918e+01
        5.0612245e+00   7.9822868e+01
        5.1020408e+00   8.0075248e+01
        5.1428571e+00   8.0325199e+01
        5.1563556e+00   8.0408163e+01
        5.1836735e+00   8.0583578e+01
        5.2244898e+00   8.0844550e+01
        5.2521158e+00   8.1020408e+01
        5.2653061e+00   8.1108214e+01
        5.3061224e+00   8.1380336e+01
        5.3443758e+00   8.1632653e+01
        5.3469388e+00   8.1650349e+01
        5.3877551e+00   8.1933767e+01
        5.4285714e+00   8.2213492e+01
        5.4331342e+00   8.2244898e+01
        5.4693878e+00   8.2506213e+01
        5.5102041e+00   8.2796919e+01
        5.5186470e+00   8.2857143e+01
        5.5510204e+00   8.3099220e+01
        5.5918367e+00   8.3401072e+01
        5.6010725e+00   8.3469388e+01
        5.6326531e+00   8.3714537e+01
        5.6734694e+00   8.4027709e+01
        5.6804946e+00   8.4081633e+01
        5.7142857e+00   8.4354138e+01
        5.7551020e+00   8.4678814e+01
        5.7569919e+00   8.4693878e+01
        5.7959184e+00   8.5020256e+01
        5.8305008e+00   8.5306122e+01
        5.8367347e+00   8.5360435e+01
        5.8775510e+00   8.5715417e+01
        5.9011353e+00   8.5918367e+01
        5.9183673e+00   8.6074870e+01
        5.9591837e+00   8.6442486e+01
        5.9690123e+00   8.6530612e+01
        6.0000000e+00   8.6824269e+01
        1.5000000e+02   1.4000000e+01
        4.3240411e+00   1.0000000e+02
        4.2857143e+00   9.9613741e+01
        4.2636816e+00   9.9387755e+01
        4.2448980e+00   9.9193034e+01
        4.2052989e+00   9.8775510e+01
        4.2040816e+00   9.8762530e+01
        4.1632653e+00   9.8317231e+01
        4.1493857e+00   9.8163265e+01
        4.1224490e+00   9.7861125e+01
        4.0952280e+00   9.7551020e+01
        4.0816327e+00   9.7394311e+01
        4.0426990e+00   9.6938776e+01
        4.0408163e+00   9.6916472e+01
        4.0000000e+00   9.6423889e+01
        1.6000000e+02   7.0000000e+01
        4.0000000e+00   7.6425199e+01
        4.0408163e+00   7.6529457e+01
        4.0816327e+00   7.6641210e+01
        4.1136494e+00   7.6734694e+01
        4.1224490e+00   7.6761681e+01
        4.1632653e+00   7.6895961e+01
        4.2040816e+00   7.7035397e+01
        4.2448980e+00   7.7179407e+01
        4.2857143e+00   7.7327481e+01
        4.2908269e+00   7.7346939e+01
        4.3265306e+00   7.7489370e+01
        4.3673469e+00   7.7655677e+01
        4.4081633e+00   7.7824522e+01
        4.4401086e+00   7.7959184e+01
        4.4489796e+00   7.7998382e+01
        4.4897959e+00   7.8184237e+01
        4.5306122e+00   7.8371372e+01
        4.5714286e+00   7.8559610e+01
        4.5739204e+00   7.8571429e+01
        4.6122449e+00   7.8761825e+01
        4.6530612e+00   7.8965165e+01
        4.6938776e+00   7.9168656e+01
        4.6968231e+00   7.9183673e+01
        4.7346939e+00   7.9385954e+01
        4.7755102e+00   7.9603736e+01
        4.8115366e+00   7.9795918e+01
        4.8163265e+00   7.9822715e+01
        4.8571429e+00   8.0054802e+01
        4.8979592e+00   8.0285525e+01
        4.9195454e+00   8.0408163e+01
        4.9387755e+00   8.0522765e+01
        4.9795918e+00   8.0767122e+01
        5.0204082e+00   8.1009500e+01
        5.0222203e+00   8.1020408e+01
        5.0612245e+00   8.1266751e+01
        5.1020408e+00   8.1522173e+01
        5.1196449e+00   8.1632653e+01
        5.1428571e+00   8.1785667e+01
        5.1836735e+00   8.2054226e+01
        5.2128058e+00   8.2244898e+01
        5.2244898e+00   8.2325313e+01
        5.2653061e+00   8.2607119e+01
        5.3019218e+00   8.2857143e+01
        5.3061224e+00   8.2887340e+01
        5.3469388e+00   8.3182520e+01
        5.3871893e+00   8.3469388e+01
        5.3877551e+00   8.3473638e+01
        5.4285714e+00   8.3782334e+01
        5.4687853e+00   8.4081633e+01
        5.4693878e+00   8.4086365e+01
        5.5102041e+00   8.4408728e+01
        5.5468702e+00   8.4693878e+01
        5.5510204e+00   8.4727989e+01
        5.5918367e+00   8.5064176e+01
        5.6215904e+00   8.5306122e+01
        5.6326531e+00   8.5401334e+01
        5.6734694e+00   8.5751502e+01
        5.6930799e+00   8.5918367e+01
        5.7142857e+00   8.6109633e+01
        5.7551020e+00   8.6473934e+01
        5.7614623e+00   8.6530612e+01
        5.7959184e+00   8.6856602e+01
        5.8265951e+00   8.7142857e+01
        5.8367347e+00   8.7243593e+01
        5.8775510e+00   8.7646516e+01
        5.8886276e+00   8.7755102e+01
        5.9183673e+00   8.8066084e+01
        5.9475525e+00   8.8367347e+01
        5.9591837e+00   8.8495836e+01
        6.0000000e+00   8.8942147e+01
        1.6000000e+02   2.4000000e+01
        4.5506431e+00   1.0000000e+02
        4.5306122e+00   9.9831249e+01
        4.4897959e+00   9.9478819e+01
        4.4795429e+00   9.9387755e+01
        4.4489796e+00   9.9112286e+01
        4.4122978e+00   9.8775510e+01
        4.4081633e+00   9.8736958e+01
        4.3673469e+00   9.8345788e+01
        4.3486680e+00   9.8163265e+01
        4.3265306e+00   9.7943596e+01
        4.2876242e+00   9.7551020e+01
        4.2857143e+00   9.7531433e+01
        4.2448980e+00   9.7102427e+01
        4.2295871e+00   9.6938776e+01
        4.2040816e+00   9.6661722e+01
        4.1736880e+00   9.6326531e+01
        4.1632653e+00   9.6209607e+01
        4.1224490e+00   9.5744306e+01
        4.1198682e+00   9.5714286e+01
        4.0816327e+00   9.5261910e+01
        4.0683047e+00   9.5102041e+01
        4.0408163e+00   9.4766345e+01
        4.0184672e+00   9.4489796e+01
        4.0000000e+00   9.4256897e+01
        1.7000000e+02   7.3000000e+01
        4.0000000e+00   7.8451618e+01
        4.0408163e+00   7.8503529e+01
        4.0816327e+00   7.8570123e+01
        4.0822790e+00   7.8571429e+01
        4.1224490e+00   7.8657615e+01
        4.1632653e+00   7.8756909e+01
        4.2040816e+00   7.8866308e+01
        4.2448980e+00   7.8984504e+01
        4.2857143e+00   7.9110389e+01
        4.3079260e+00   7.9183673e+01
        4.3265306e+00   7.9248662e+01
        4.3673469e+00   7.9399818e+01
        4.4081633e+00   7.9555921e+01
        4.4489796e+00   7.9716351e+01
        4.4684377e+00   7.9795918e+01
        4.4897959e+00   7.9888246e+01
        4.5306122e+00   8.0070331e+01
        4.5714286e+00   8.0254793e+01
        4.6048104e+00   8.0408163e+01
        4.6122449e+00   8.0444271e+01
        4.6530612e+00   8.0648840e+01
        4.6938776e+00   8.0854206e+01
        4.7266221e+00   8.1020408e+01
        4.7346939e+00   8.1063719e+01
        4.7755102e+00   8.1287865e+01
        4.8163265e+00   8.1511517e+01
        4.8382019e+00   8.1632653e+01
        4.8571429e+00   8.1743546e+01
        4.8979592e+00   8.1984825e+01
        4.9387755e+00   8.2224552e+01
        4.9421757e+00   8.2244898e+01
        4.9795918e+00   8.2481657e+01
        5.0204082e+00   8.2737997e+01
        5.0392831e+00   8.2857143e+01
        5.0612245e+00   8.3003800e+01
        5.1020408e+00   8.3276783e+01
        5.1309676e+00   8.3469388e+01
        5.1428571e+00   8.3553332e+01
        5.1836735e+00   8.3843008e+01
        5.2176475e+00   8.4081633e+01
        5.2244898e+00   8.4132669e+01
        5.2653061e+00   8.4439098e+01
        5.2996858e+00   8.4693878e+01
        5.3061224e+00   8.4744615e+01
        5.3469388e+00   8.5067863e+01
        5.3773997e+00   8.5306122e+01
        5.3877551e+00   8.5392423e+01
        5.4285714e+00   8.5732551e+01
        5.4510682e+00   8.5918367e+01
        5.4693878e+00   8.6079876e+01
        5.5102041e+00   8.6436928e+01
        5.5209386e+00   8.6530612e+01
        5.5510204e+00   8.6811379e+01
        5.5870726e+00   8.7142857e+01
        5.5918367e+00   8.7189871e+01
        5.6326531e+00   8.7592076e+01
        5.6493754e+00   8.7755102e+01
        5.6734694e+00   8.8007796e+01
        5.7082310e+00   8.8367347e+01
        5.7142857e+00   8.8435013e+01
        5.7551020e+00   8.8888245e+01
        5.7633967e+00   8.8979592e+01
        5.7959184e+00   8.9367655e+01
        5.8149472e+00   8.9591837e+01
        5.8367347e+00   8.9871445e+01
        5.8629743e+00   9.0204082e+01
        5.8775510e+00   9.0406623e+01
        5.9073862e+00   9.0816327e+01
        5.9183673e+00   9.0982813e+01
        5.9481017e+00   9.1428571e+01
        5.9591837e+00   9.1613577e+01
        5.9850515e+00   9.2040816e+01
        6.0000000e+00   9.2318633e+01
        1.7000000e+02   3.6000000e+01
        4.8808347e+00   1.0000000e+02
        4.8571429e+00   9.9860467e+01
        4.8163265e+00   9.9609120e+01
        4.7816445e+00   9.9387755e+01
        4.7755102e+00   9.9347693e+01
        4.7346939e+00   9.9068272e+01
        4.6938776e+00   9.8781617e+01
        4.6930467e+00   9.8775510e+01
        4.6530612e+00   9.8475110e+01
        4.6123817e+00   9.8163265e+01
        4.6122449e+00   9.8162192e+01
        4.5714286e+00   9.7828933e+01
        4.5380253e+00   9.7551020e+01
        4.5306122e+00   9.7487902e+01
        4.4897959e+00   9.7129276e+01
        4.4685824e+00   9.6938776e+01
        4.4489796e+00   9.6758622e+01
        4.4081633e+00   9.6375929e+01
        4.4030416e+00   9.6326531e+01
        4.3673469e+00   9.5974210e+01
        4.3414197e+00   9.5714286e+01
        4.3265306e+00   9.5561318e+01
        4.2857143e+00   9.5134800e+01
        4.2826551e+00   9.5102041e+01
        4.2448980e+00   9.4687706e+01
        4.2271116e+00   9.4489796e+01
        4.2040816e+00   9.4226794e+01
        4.1739002e+00   9.3877551e+01
        4.1632653e+00   9.3751042e+01
        4.1229386e+00   9.3265306e+01
        4.1224490e+00   9.3259232e+01
        4.0816327e+00   9.2743796e+01
        4.0745342e+00   9.2653061e+01
        4.0408163e+00   9.2209222e+01
        4.0281639e+00   9.2040816e+01
        4.0000000e+00   9.1654023e+01
        1.8000000e+02   1.3300000e+02
        4.0000000e+00   8.1851338e+01
        4.0408163e+00   8.1651252e+01
        4.0465757e+00   8.1632653e+01
        4.0816327e+00   8.1546204e+01
        4.1224490e+00   8.1491723e+01
        4.1632653e+00   8.1475216e+01
        4.2040816e+00   8.1489632e+01
        4.2448980e+00   8.1529514e+01
        4.2857143e+00   8.1590578e+01
        4.3069971e+00   8.1632653e+01
        4.3265306e+00   8.1674505e+01
        4.3673469e+00   8.1780523e+01
        4.4081633e+00   8.1899874e+01
        4.4489796e+00   8.2030446e+01
        4.4897959e+00   8.2170522e+01
        4.5098519e+00   8.2244898e+01
        4.5306122e+00   8.2327791e+01
        4.5714286e+00   8.2500899e+01
        4.6122449e+00   8.2679290e+01
        4.6518986e+00   8.2857143e+01
        4.6530612e+00   8.2862755e+01
        4.6938776e+00   8.3071074e+01
        4.7346939e+00   8.3281426e+01
        4.7707192e+00   8.3469388e+01
        4.7755102e+00   8.3496280e+01
        4.8163265e+00   8.3733902e+01
        4.8571429e+00   8.3971041e+01
        4.8758415e+00   8.4081633e+01
        4.8979592e+00   8.4222346e+01
        4.9387755e+00   8.4484431e+01
        4.9714564e+00   8.4693878e+01
        4.9795918e+00   8.4750081e+01
        5.0204082e+00   8.5036938e+01
        5.0592260e+00   8.5306122e+01
        5.0612245e+00   8.5321096e+01
        5.1020408e+00   8.5632537e+01
        5.1401722e+00   8.5918367e+01
        5.1428571e+00   8.5940166e+01
        5.1836735e+00   8.6275966e+01
        5.2151193e+00   8.6530612e+01
        5.2244898e+00   8.6613020e+01
        5.2653061e+00   8.6972881e+01
        5.2847401e+00   8.7142857e+01
        5.3061224e+00   8.7346552e+01
        5.3469388e+00   8.7730050e+01
        5.3495904e+00   8.7755102e+01
        5.3877551e+00   8.8149087e+01
        5.4092300e+00   8.8367347e+01
        5.4285714e+00   8.8583592e+01
        5.4645230e+00   8.8979592e+01
        5.4693878e+00   8.9039009e+01
        5.5102041e+00   8.9533508e+01
        5.5150577e+00   8.9591837e+01
        5.5510204e+00   9.0073414e+01
        5.5609089e+00   9.0204082e+01
        5.5918367e+00   9.0664336e+01
        5.6021794e+00   9.0816327e+01
        5.6326531e+00   9.1327334e+01
        5.6387623e+00   9.1428571e+01
        5.6704257e+00   9.2040816e+01
        5.6734694e+00   9.2112391e+01
        5.6967011e+00   9.2653061e+01
        5.7142857e+00   9.3162904e+01
        5.7178516e+00   9.3265306e+01
        5.7327237e+00   9.3877551e+01
        5.7412557e+00   9.4489796e+01
        5.7423431e+00   9.5102041e+01
        5.7346199e+00   9.5714286e+01
        5.7163772e+00   9.6326531e+01
        5.7142857e+00   9.6371012e+01
        5.6829876e+00   9.6938776e+01
        5.6734694e+00   9.7061618e+01
        5.6326531e+00   9.7501278e+01
        5.6270560e+00   9.7551020e+01
        5.5918367e+00   9.7799893e+01
        5.5510204e+00   9.8027767e+01
        5.5195201e+00   9.8163265e+01
        5.5102041e+00   9.8197052e+01
        5.4693878e+00   9.8309964e+01
        5.4285714e+00   9.8386986e+01
        5.3877551e+00   9.8431737e+01
        5.3469388e+00   9.8447332e+01
        5.3061224e+00   9.8436458e+01
        5.2653061e+00   9.8401454e+01
        5.2244898e+00   9.8344357e+01
        5.1836735e+00   9.8266954e+01
        5.1428571e+00   9.8170818e+01
        5.1402179e+00   9.8163265e+01
        5.1020408e+00   9.8049110e+01
        5.0612245e+00   9.7910242e+01
        5.0204082e+00   9.7756080e+01
        4.9795918e+00   9.7587732e+01
        4.9715368e+00   9.7551020e+01
        4.9387755e+00   9.7395597e+01
        4.8979592e+00   9.7188609e+01
        4.8571429e+00   9.6970405e+01
        4.8516453e+00   9.6938776e+01
        4.8163265e+00   9.6727606e+01
        4.7755102e+00   9.6473373e+01
        4.7530180e+00   9.6326531e+01
        4.7346939e+00   9.6202152e+01
        4.6938776e+00   9.5912868e+01
        4.6667629e+00   9.5714286e+01
        4.6530612e+00   9.5609911e+01
        4.6122449e+00   9.5286933e+01
        4.5895229e+00   9.5102041e+01
        4.5714286e+00   9.4948837e+01
        4.5306122e+00   9.4593918e+01
        4.5190003e+00   9.4489796e+01
        4.4897959e+00   9.4217221e+01
        4.4539199e+00   9.3877551e+01
        4.4489796e+00   9.3828719e+01
        4.4081633e+00   9.3413738e+01
        4.3938216e+00   9.3265306e+01
        4.3673469e+00   9.2979148e+01
        4.3375445e+00   9.2653061e+01
        4.3265306e+00   9.2526780e+01
        4.2857143e+00   9.2052919e+01
        4.2846954e+00   9.2040816e+01
        4.2448980e+00   9.1545275e+01
        4.2356225e+00   9.1428571e+01
        4.2040816e+00   9.1010970e+01
        4.1895206e+00   9.0816327e+01
        4.1632653e+00   9.0445386e+01
        4.1463344e+00   9.0204082e+01
        4.1224490e+00   8.9842477e+01
        4.1060237e+00   8.9591837e+01
        4.0816327e+00   8.9194187e+01
        4.0685629e+00   8.8979592e+01
        4.0408163e+00   8.8489555e+01
        4.0339401e+00   8.8367347e+01
        4.0023142e+00   8.7755102e+01
        4.0000000e+00   8.7704798e+01
        1.9000000e+02   4.5000000e+01
        4.5200123e+00   8.7755102e+01
        4.5306122e+00   8.7577639e+01
        4.5714286e+00   8.7274969e+01
        4.6122449e+00   8.7217025e+01
        4.6530612e+00   8.7275039e+01
        4.6938776e+00   8.7396703e+01
        4.7346939e+00   8.7556762e+01
        4.7755102e+00   8.7741531e+01
        4.7780008e+00   8.7755102e+01
        4.8163265e+00   8.8010053e+01
        4.8571429e+00   8.8283139e+01
        4.8688362e+00   8.8367347e+01
        4.8979592e+00   8.8627356e+01
        4.9385423e+00   8.8979592e+01
        4.9387755e+00   8.8982237e+01
        4.9795918e+00   8.9457757e+01
        4.9913567e+00   8.9591837e+01
        5.0204082e+00   9.0037788e+01
        5.0314662e+00   9.0204082e+01
        5.0576612e+00   9.0816327e+01
        5.0612245e+00   9.1132376e+01
        5.0646202e+00   9.1428571e+01
        5.0612245e+00   9.1536902e+01
        5.0315876e+00   9.2040816e+01
        5.0204082e+00   9.2108169e+01
        4.9795918e+00   9.2215904e+01
        4.9387755e+00   9.2215078e+01
        4.8979592e+00   9.2142441e+01
        4.8648617e+00   9.2040816e+01
        4.8571429e+00   9.2012051e+01
        4.8163265e+00   9.1804435e+01
        4.7755102e+00   9.1573199e+01
        4.7528156e+00   9.1428571e+01
        4.7346939e+00   9.1290460e+01
        4.6938776e+00   9.0958245e+01
        4.6773809e+00   9.0816327e+01
        4.6530612e+00   9.0563279e+01
        4.6186351e+00   9.0204082e+01
        4.6122449e+00   9.0119176e+01
        4.5725466e+00   8.9591837e+01
        4.5714286e+00   8.9571205e+01
        4.5392628e+00   8.8979592e+01
        4.5306122e+00   8.8715050e+01
        4.5191688e+00   8.8367347e+01
        4.5200123e+00   8.7755102e+01
        };%{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Does someone have an explanation or solution for this problem? I prefer to load my data from a file rather than pasting it directly into Latex.

Thanks a lot in advance,

René

Comment: I think this might be due to numerical inaccuracies introduced by the `\pgfplotstableread` command. If you load the file directly from the file system (using `\addplot ... table {datafile.dat}`), the plot is correct.

Comment: @René, does Jake's suggestion help you or do you need further assistance? In the first case I would vote to close the question as being solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Jake's comment should solve the question.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I'm confused - since when are (were?) questions closed as off-topic when they are solved by comments? Shouldn't the comment simply have been turned into an answer?